# SFDX Package Dependencies and Package Version Create

Tags: salesforcedx

I have two Unlocked packages, one is dependent upon another. The first package directory is my default package directory, so `force:source:pull` drops new things from my scratch org into package directory 1.

I created a workflow rule in my scratch org and pulled it into my project but I wanted it to be in package directory 2, so I moved it manually into that directory. All is well.

I went to create package versions for both packages and package 1 successfully created a version. Creating a version for package 2 is failing due to the following error:

" You're trying to include Workflow Account_Snapshot__c in Package 0.1. This component already exists in Package 0.1, which Package 0.1 depends on. You can't include the same component in both packages."

I moved that workflow into the second package directory though and out of the first. I've even installed the first package's new version into a scratch org and sandbox and that component is definitely not a part of the first package, though my CLI thinks so and the package version create fails. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you didn't leave any sign of it in folder workflow or any other. Cause processes and flows often create more then one file and the other file just register it as part of package, second ( the one you moved ) is the design of it.